# Which tags should I specify for email HTML

Tags: html, email

If I send an HTML via email, should I still specify such tags like `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<head>`?

Or should I just send the `<body>` content directly? Will most popular email clients display such image in the correct way?

Comment: There are multi-page tutorials and even a book on this subject making it far too broad of a question.

Comment: This is also dependent on which client you expect your users to see the email in. Most of the popular email clients are slowly adopting more modern HTML standards, but you'll have to do research.

Answer (score -1):

It depends.

Every mail client is different, and every message is different, which is why the proper approach would be to perform testing on multiple clients before sending your message.

Back in my bulk mail days, I did extensive testing and even had different logic based on the recipient's domain. For example, using `<div>` in Gmail and `<p>` for Yahoo.

There's a good reason people pay for mail services like Constant Contact and Mail Chimp. It takes a lot of work to stay on top of these things.